# Tkinter using 2d array to as values for the entries

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a program where it asks the users the size of the matrix then creates a matrix of the given size and creates another set of entries to show the solution. The problem is how do I use the values of the 2d array as the values of each entry for the solution matrix. I tried using .insert method but it only appears blank.
I just use the answer array for example and testing.

```
from tkinter import *
from ttkbootstrap.constants import *
import ttkbootstrap as tb
import os

os.environ['TK_SILENCE_DEPRECATION'] = '1'

root = tb.Window(themename="solar")  # dark mode
# root = tb.Window(themename="cerculean") # light mode

root.title("RREF CALCULATOR")

root.geometry('1000x800')
root.resizable(False, False)
mytitle = tb.Label(text="Find the RREF of a Matrix from 2x2 to 5x5", font=('helvetica', 29), bootstyle=DEFAULT)

setup = tb.Frame(root, bootstyle=DEFAULT)
setup.place(x=380, y=150)

setupMatrix = tb.Frame(root)
setupMatrix.place(x=150, y=450)

answerMatrix = tb.Frame(root)
answerMatrix.place(x=700, y=450)

# labels for row and col,
row = tb.Label(setup, text="Enter number of Rows", font=('helvetica', 18), bootstyle=DEFAULT)
col = tb.Label(setup, text="Enter number of Columns", font=('helvetica', 18), bootstyle=DEFAULT)

matrixSize = ["2", "3", "4", "5"]
answer = [[1,2],
          [3,4]]

myButton = tb.Button(setup, text="Create matrix", bootstyle=DEFAULT, command=lambda: setCol(setupMatrix))
resetButton = tb.Button(setup, text="Reset", bootstyle=DEFAULT, command=lambda: resetMatrix(setupMatrix, rowCombo, colCombo))
solveButton = tb.Button(root, text="Solve Matrix", bootstyle=DEFAULT, command=lambda: solveMatrix(setupMatrix, answerMatrix))
# dropdowns for the size of the matrix
colCombo = tb.Combobox(setup, bootstyle=DEFAULT, values=matrixSize)
colCombo.current(0)
rowCombo = tb.Combobox(setup, bootstyle=DEFAULT, values=matrixSize)
rowCombo.current(0)

row.pack(pady=5)
rowCombo.pack(pady=5)
col.pack(pady=5)
colCombo.pack(pady=10)
myButton.pack(side=LEFT)
resetButton.pack(side=RIGHT)
mytitle.pack(pady=50)
solveButton.pack(pady=250)

class Table:
    def setCol(self, setupMatrix):
        colSize = int(colCombo.get())
        rowSize = int(rowCombo.get())

        for i in range(rowSize):
            for j in range(colSize):
                entry = Entry(setupMatrix, width=5, fg='blue', font=('Arial', 16, 'bold'))
                entry.grid(row=i, column=j)

    def showAnswer(self, answerMatrix,answer):
        colSize = int(colCombo.get())
        rowSize = int(rowCombo.get())

        answer_widgets = []

        for i in range(rowSize):
            row_widgets = []
            for j in range(colSize):
                answer = Entry(answerMatrix, width=5, fg='blue', font=('Arial', 16, 'bold'))
                answer.grid(row=i, column=j)
                answer_widgets.append(answer)
                row_widgets.append(answer)

            answer_widgets.append(row_widgets)

                # answer.insert(END, str(answer[i][j]))  # You can set the initial value as needed
        for i in range(rowSize):
            for j in range(colSize):
                answer_widgets[i][j].insert(END, str(answer[i][j]))

def setCol(setupMatrix):
    table_instance.setCol(setupMatrix)

def resetMatrix(setupMatrix, rowCombo, colCombo):
    for widget in setupMatrix.winfo_children():
        widget.destroy()
    rowCombo.set('')  # Clear the selected value in the combobox
    colCombo.set('')  # Clear the selected value in the combobox

def solveMatrix(setupMatrix, answerMatrix):
    cols, rows = setupMatrix.grid_size()
    matrix_values = [
        [int(setupMatrix.grid_slaves(row=row, column=col)[0].get())  # Convert to int
         for col in range(cols)] for row in range(rows)
    ]
    table_instance.showAnswer(answerMatrix,answer)

    print(matrix_values)

# Create an instance of the Table class
table_instance = Table()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You override argument `answer` by `answer = Entry(...)` inside `showAnswer()`.  Note also that using `colSize = int(colCombo.get())` may have issue because the selection of those comboboxes may change after clicking `Create matrix` button but before clicking `Solve Matrix` button.

Comment: It would help if you could reduce the amount of code. For example, is ttkbootstrap necessary to be able to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have overwritten the argument `answer` by the line `answer = Entry(...)` inside `showAnswer()`.  Use another name for the entry widget.

Also getting the grid size using the current values of the comboboxes inside `showAnswer()` may raise exception if those values are changed before clicking the `Solve Matrix` button.  Use the argument `answer` to determine the grid size instead:

```py
def showAnswer(self, answerMatrix, answer):
    #colSize = int(colCombo.get())
    #rowSize = int(rowCombo.get())
    # use argument "answer" to determine the grid size
    rowSize = len(answer)
    colSize = len(answer[0])

    answer_widgets = []

    for i in range(rowSize):
        row_widgets = []
        for j in range(colSize):
            # use other name instead of 'answer' fo the entry box
            entry = Entry(answerMatrix, width=5, fg='blue', font=('Arial', 16, 'bold'))
            entry.grid(row=i, column=j)
            #answer_widgets.append(answer) # should not call it here
            row_widgets.append(entry)

        answer_widgets.append(row_widgets)

    for i in range(rowSize):
        for j in range(colSize):
            answer_widgets[i][j].insert(END, str(answer[i][j]))
```